# Series prove or disprove statement

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

> Let $a_n$ be a sequence.
>
> $\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n =0 $ then the series: $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n, \ \sum_{n=1}^\infty (a_n+a_{n+1}) $ converge and diverge together.

It doesn't seem right, there are no convergence tests that fit this question yet every counterexample I try does not seem to work.

Is this how I should see the sum?

$\sum_{n=1}^\infty (a_n+a_{n+1})=2\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n +a_{n+1}$

If so then there's no real difference between the two series since you multiply it by a constant and add just one more value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT:

Observe that

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty (a_n+a_{n+1}) = 2\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n -a_1$$

Comment: I don't really understand why the floor and ceiling function but other than that, it's essentially the same as what I wrote, so the two series are the same.

Comment: @GinKin, awfully sorry for the confusion. I wanted to separate  $2\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$  and $a_1$

Comment: @labbhattacharjee In such cases, I find that it is better to write it as $-a_1+ 2 \sum a_n$, just for clarity on the summation. Could also use parenthesis (which you did. those are not the floor/ceiling function)

Comment: @CalvinLin, thanks. Good idea

Answer (score 6):

Recall that the series $\displaystyle\sum_{n\ge1}a_n$ is convergent if and only if the sequence
$\displaystyle\left(\sum_{k=1}^na_k\right)_n$ is convergent.

Now by this equality
$$\sum_{k=1}^n(a_{k+1}+a_k)-\sum_{k=1}^na_k=\sum_{k=1}^na_{k+1}=\sum_{k=1}^na_{k}-a_1+a_{n+1}$$
and since $\displaystyle\lim_n a_n=0$ we can deduce the desired result.

Comment: I never saw a sequence made out of a series.

Comment: That was just a funny way to denote the sequence of partial sums of the series, @GinKin

Comment: Clever, @Sami! I like this answer! +1